# How to login to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, login, password

I want to avoid having to enter my password when I initially log in to Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Settings app:
2. Go to Users
   [image: Screenshot of Gnome Settings Users section.]
3. Click "Unlock..." near the top-right
4. Click "Automatic Login"

Comment: What I get is a box that says login keyring didn't get authenticated.  What is the login keyring?

Comment: That's vital information. Add it to your question. You will get better answers if your question is complete.

Comment: @jvrounds the login keyring is a list of passwords, authentication keys and browser cookies. They are encrypted with your user's password, so while you can login automatically Gnome can't access your keyring for some data it wants to use, although there might be ways around it.